# AWS API Gateway CORS issue - JS

Tags: javascript, cors

Im experiencing abit of problem with CORs request and im not sure what im doing wrong.

I use the following code to post to my API Gateway in AWS and its coming back with the following error: "Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

But in my preflight response, its Access-Control-Allow-Origin is '*'

Here is my JS code:

```
<input type="button" id="click" value="Click Me">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

    var settings = {
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "url": url,
          "method": "POST",
          "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
        }
    }

        $("#click").click(function() {
            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                alert(response);
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<p id='test'></p>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!
Pon

Edit:

Added full set of request and response

General

```
.   Request URL: https://apikey.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/
.   Request Method: OPTIONS
.   Status Code: 200 
.   Remote Address: 54.230.135.63:443
.   Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response Headers

```
.   access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
.   access-control-allow-methods: DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT
.   access-control-allow-origin: *
.   content-length: 0
.   content-type: application/json
.   date: Wed, 14 Mar 2018 05:54:46 GMT
.   status: 200
.   via: 1.1 d112d3017705f4a4c66a2958899eb08b.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
.   x-amz-cf-id: 97nK6qkoiCsMa6TvJvWGUYEevT2bWE4nlKcM8P8sthVeIk9E2BPN9Q==
.   x-amzn-requestid: 33279618-274c-11e8-97da-ffa5e9493919
.   x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
```

Request Headers

```
.   :authority: apikey.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
.   :method: OPTIONS
.   :path: /outageCheck?test=test
.   :scheme: https
.   accept: */*
.   accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
.   accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
.   access-control-request-headers: access-control-allow-origin,cache-control
.   access-control-request-method: POST
.   origin: http://127.0.0.1:62332
.   user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36
```

Console Error:

Failed to load https://apikey.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/outageCheck?test=test: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: I tried this script with a remote URL, it seems to work. Have you tried hitting some other `API`?

Comment: Can you PLEASE include a full set of request AND response headers that you're seeing, for both the preflight OPTIONS request (if any) and also the GET/POST request that you're trying to make.

Comment: Definitely can, see my edit, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post should help you enable CORS on your API gateway

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

> 1. Sign in to the API Gateway console at
>      https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway.
> 2. In the API Gateway console, choose an API under APIs.
> 3. Choose a resource under Resources. This will enable CORS for all the
>      methods on the resource. Alternatively, you could choose a method under the resource to enable
>      CORS for just this method.
> 4. Choose Enable CORS from the Actions drop-down menu.
>
>    - Choose Enable CORS
> 5. In the Enable CORS form, do the following:
>
>    - In the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` input field, type a static string
>        of a comma-separated list of headers that the client must submit in
>        the actual request of the resource. Use the console-provided header
>        list of
>        `Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token`
>        or specify your own headers.
>    - Use the console-provided value of '*' as the
>        Access-Control-Allow-Origin header value to allow access requests from
>        all domains, or specify a named domain to all access requests from the
>        specified domain.
>    - Choose Enable CORS and replace existing CORS headers.
> 6. In Confirm method changes, choose Yes, overwrite existing values to
>      confirm the new CORS settings.

Comment: Thanks Gokul, i've actually enabled CORS on my AWS API Gateway already which in turn automatically created an option method. Ensured that the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is '*' and keeping the default headers provided. I've actually tried the above JS code to post via postman and it seems to work, im actually using my local machine writing client side code, could this be the problem? The api is returning JSON

Comment: Have you tried removing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `cache-control` header from the request and trying? They are not in the list of allowed `Headers` returned by the `OPTIONS` response.

Comment: Thank Gokul, i've tried 2 methods from your suggestion, added Access-Control-Allow-Origin and cache-control header  to my option response and actually removed it entirely, now im getting this error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." even though im setting it in my js or removing it from my js. ahhhh, im pulling my hair out with this. Thank you so much for your help and time.