# How to CALL api using Aws sdk angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, promise, aws-sdk

I Have created request using AWS and want to call my AWS SDk API API. 
Below is my whole code.

```
var endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(AWS.config.domain);
var request = new AWS.HttpRequest(endpoint, AWS.config.region);
 AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.Credentials('somevalue', 'somevalue', '');
var signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(request, 'es',true);
signer.addAuthorization(AWS.config.credentials, new Date());
request.body = JSON.stringify({
            'query': {
                my value
        });
```

Now i have ready object request and i need to call my API.but i don't know which AWS or http  method i need  to use invoke.I have tried below options but not successful .I also used request.on method but it says it is not supported.

```
`var promise = request.promise();
    promise.then(
        function(body) {
          console.log("yes")
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("no")
        }
    );
```

I also used below Code to invoke but it fails and give errors.

```
    var client = new AWS.HttpClient();
        client.handleRequest(request,null,function(response) {
            console.log(response.statusCode + ' ' + response.statusMessage);
            var responseBody = '';
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
              responseBody += chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', function (chunk) {
              console.log('Response body: ' + responseBody);
            });
          }, function(error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
          });

core.js:1448 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'xhrAsync' of null
    at features.constructor.handleRequest (xhr.js:63)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you provide is only an example of promise based syntax. To learn more about the aws-sdk I recommend reading their docs.

Another answer on usage of the aws-sdk can be found here:

[How do I use AWS sdk definitions for TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225183/how-do-i-use-aws-sdk-definitions-for-typescript)

And AWS offers documentation on their package here:

https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-javascript/

Here's a great example of usage:

https://gist.github.com/ckimrie/96e4992036c559c1f046476d3fc16a7e

...showing the relevant snippet:

```
//---- Angular 2 Http Service Example ----
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

@Injectable()
export class ApiGatewayService {

 constructor(private http:Http){

let creds = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: "eu-west-1:xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
});

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'eu-west-1',
  credentials: creds
});

AWS.config.credentials.get((err) => {
  if(err) throw err;

  let httpRequest = new AWS.HttpRequest("https://xxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/my/api", "eu-west-1");
  httpRequest.method = "POST";
  httpRequest.headers.host = "xxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
  httpRequest.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json";
  httpRequest.body = JSON.stringify({
    data: {
      username: 'foo',
      password: 'bar',
      applicationName: 'biz',
    }
  });

  let v4signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(httpRequest, "execute-api", true);
  v4signer.addAuthorization(AWS.config.credentials, AWS.util.date.getDate());

  //Create a headers object from the AWS signed request
  let headers = new Headers();
  for(let key of Object.keys(httpRequest.headers)){
    headers.set(key, httpRequest.headers[key]);
  }
  headers.delete('host'); //Browser throws a warning if attempting to set host header
  this.http.post(httpRequest.endpoint.href, httpRequest.body, {
    method: httpRequest.method,
    search: httpRequest.endpoint.search,
    headers: headers
  }).subscribe((data)=>{
    console.log(data); //Success
  });
})
 }
}
```

Comment: @kyle.Thanks for the reply,I have edited my question can you provide more details.i went through your provided links but it was not much.

Comment: extended my answer to provide a link to a gist with usage of this portion of the aws sdk

Comment: Thanks for the Great reply.i partially worked.Getting error Request header field X-Amz-User-Agent is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.Can you provide some detail how to solve this

Comment: This is a different issue than your original post, but you can find an answer to this here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249018/aws-api-gateway-cors-issue-js

I recommend to upvote and accept as answer if my post solves your initial question.